# get the captcha url by reading the page source in java(the captcha is generated by javascript file embeded in page html source)

Tags: javascript, java, url, captcha, httpconnection

I want to get the URL of captcha image in java.First, i read the page source by making a HTTP connection with "GET" method. i couldn't find the captcha in the page source code in intelijidea console and i understood that the captcha is generated by a Javascript file which is embedded in the HTML file.(something like ). even when i read the javascript file i could only find a raw method which generate the captcha URL and unfortunately i couldn't find the return value.
Is there any solution for getting the captcha URl by making a HTTP connection in this situation?
i don't wnat to use any API or library.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you referring to a specific website's captcha image?

Comment: yes exactly but i'm not really eager to publish the website address here